# SQL Server : one to many select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join

I have two tables, logically related one to many.

First table:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255), 
    Age int
);
```

Second table:

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles 
(
    Brand varchar(50), 
    PersonID int,

    FOREIGN KEY(PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(ID)
);
```

My approach is to list each of the Persons and the vehicles that this Person own.

What I managed to do:

```
SELECT LastName, brand 
FROM vehicles
INNER JOIN Persons ON Persons.ID = PersonID
ORDER BY LastName ASC
```

Unfortunately this is not what I have in mind to do, which is to display every Person **once** and next to it a list of **vehicles** for ex.:

```
User1 | kia, ford, jeep
User2 | ferrari, harley
```

Is it doable and if so what is the appropriate way? Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`FOR XML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server) with `SUFF` for this:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,
STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + v.Brand
    FROM vehicles as v
    WHERE v.PersonID = p.ID
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Vehicles
FROM Persons AS p;
```

- [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5355a/3)

Results:

```
| FirstName | LastName |        Vehicles |
|-----------|----------|-----------------|
|     User1 |    user1 | Ford, kia, jeep |
|     User2 |    User2 |  ferrri, harley |
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, yes you are right.

Comment: thank you, it works fine. How can this been update in order to exclude those Persons that not have vehicles? Because so far I am getting all Persons with null on Vehicles(if they don't own vehicles).Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The most recent version of SQL Server (SQL Server 2017) finally has this functionality built-in.  So you can do:

```
SELECT p.LastName,
       STRING_AGG(v.brand, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.brand) as vehicles
FROM Persons p JOIN
     vehicles v
     ON p.ID = v.PersonID
GROUP BY p.ID, p.LastName;
```

When you have a query with more than one table, I would advise you to always use table aliases and qualified column names.

If you want people without vehicles to be included, then use a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: thank you but unfortunately I am using an older version of SQL Server.